Simple coordinate transformation for simple tensor?
I’m working with the metric
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}f&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-r^2&0\\0&0&0&-r^2\sin^2\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
for a function of $r$ and $t$, $f$, with the standard spherical coordinate system $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ and Levi-Civita connection. The Christoffel symbols are then the standard ones (i.e. those found here) and a couple others,
$$\Gamma^t_{tr}=\Gamma^t_{rt}=\frac{f_{,r}}{2f}\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\Gamma^r_{tt}=\frac{f_{,r}}{2},$$
unless I’m mistaken. This metric should be spherically-symmetric, unless I’m doing something wrong.
When calculating the components of the Ricci/Riemann tensor I then get factors of $\sin^2\theta$ in the $\phi$-components of various indices. I expect that that’s because that shows up in the metric; for example I find that
$$R^t_{\phi t\phi}=-\frac{f_{,r}}{2f}r\sin^2\theta$$
unless I typed something out wrong. I had someone I was working with tell me that this was spherical asymmetry because it depends on $\theta$, but I maintain that the Riemann tensor must be spherically-symmetric since it’s derived entirely from the metric which also is.
The sort-of-convenient part of all this is that the Ricci tensor ends up taking the form $R_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}\operatorname{diag}(a, b, b, b)$ for some $a$ and $b$ that are hard to write out. For the sake of reinforcing my sense of security in the fact that this metric and its derived quantities are spherically symmetric I’m going to transform $R$ to rectangular coordinates; I know that in general for transforming $T_{\mu\nu}$ to $T’_{\mu\nu}$ you sum $T’_{\mu\nu}=T_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial x’^\mu}{\partial x^\alpha}\frac{\partial x’^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}$; that’s not necessarily the simplest transformation ever, so knowing $R_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}\operatorname{diag}(a, b,b,b)$ is there a simpler transformation I can do?

Where exactly in that 90p document did you find those "standard" Christoffel symbols? The metric surely not that of a sphere. Rather something with a signature that that is neither from the East $-+++$ nor from the West coast $+---$. More context please. Perhaps I could dig out some python code that calculates Christoffel symbols, and Riemann tensor from such metrics.

@KurtG. See page 19, eqn. 2.1.10a-b, of that catalogue; the “standards” are the Christoffel symbols for Minkowski spacetime in spherical coordinates (with a couple added from my choice of $g_{tt}$). I actually calculated these myself both by hand and, to check my work, with a computer algebra system (SymPy + spacetimeengine + WolframAlpha simultaeously, for certainty). I might have been slightly imprecise.

Their metric is $ds^2=-c^2dt^2+dr^2+r^2(d\vartheta^2+\sin^2\vartheta,d\varphi^2),.$ Quite standard indeed and having East coast convention. Yours as too many minus signs for my taste. Let's clarify that before tweaking the $t$ coordinate with a function $f,.$

Sorry, I meant to use WC convention on that same metric (I goofed with the minus symbols; I typed this on a mobile device and MathJax did not seem very happy with me.)

Ok. I think what is confusing you about spherical symmetry can be studied quite simply in flat Euclidean $\mathbb R^3,.$ (This is also the sector in which we can only speak of spherical symmetry in such a four-dimensional space time.) That the flat Euclidean metric is spherically symmetric is much easier seen when it is written in Cartesian coordinates $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2,.$ We know how it looks like in spherical coordinates. The appearance of $\sin^2\vartheta$ there is not a symptom of the metric having lost its spherical symmetry. In fact, a shift of that polar angle is not a rotation,

while a shift of the azimuth $\varphi$ is a rotation.

Okay, so that’s just an artifact of the coordinate system? (I don’t frequently work in spherical so I am not familiar with its quirks quite yet.) I mean, I knew my friend was wrong to begin with (derive something from something spherically-symmetric and I can’t think of a way it wouldn’t also be spherically symmetric).

Yes I think it is an artifact. Spherical coordinates single out a polar axis and therefore the origin of $\vartheta,.$ I don't know how cumbersome it is to describe a rotation not around that axis in spherical coordinates. You may want to ask your friend to do that :)

Generally, for calculations like this it is easier to keep things straight using the connection one-forms and the Cartan structure equations. For the Levi-Civita connection we will have the following;
$$\theta^i_k=\Gamma^i_{jk}\omega^j$$
Where the $\omega$'s are the co-frame to your orthonormal frame. The Cartan structure equations are;
$$d\omega^a= \theta^a_b\wedge\omega^b\\R^a_{b \space \cdot\cdot}=R^a_{bcd}(\omega^c \wedge\omega^d)=d\theta^a_b+\theta^a_c\wedge\theta^c_b$$
So, by doing some relatively simple exterior differentiation we can simply read off the non-zero components of our Riemann tensor. For your given metric
$$g=fdt^2-dr^2-r^2d\theta^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$$
we would have;
$$\omega^\hat{t}=\sqrt{f(r,t)}dt \\ \omega^\hat{r}=dr \\ \omega^\hat{\theta}=rd\theta \\ \omega^\hat{\phi}=r\sin(\theta)d\phi$$
Which then gives us;
$$d\omega^\hat{t}=\frac{f_r}{2\sqrt{f}}dr \wedge dt=\frac{f_r}{2f} \omega^\hat{r} \wedge \omega^\hat{t}\\d\omega^\hat{\theta}=dr\wedge d\theta=\frac{1}{r}\omega^\hat{r}\wedge \omega^\hat{\theta} \\ d\omega^\hat{\phi}=\sin(\theta)\space dr\wedge d\phi + r\cos(\theta)\space d\theta\wedge d\phi \\ = \frac{1}{r} d\omega^\hat{r} \wedge d\omega^\hat{\phi}+\frac{\cot(\theta)}{r} d\omega^\hat{\theta} \wedge d\omega^\hat{\phi}$$
So, by the first structure equation we have the following;
$$\theta^\hat{t}_{\hat{r}}=\frac{f_r}{2f}\omega^\hat{t}  \\ \theta^\hat{\theta}_{\hat{r}}=\frac{1}{r}\omega^\hat{\theta}\\ \theta^\hat{\phi}_{\hat{r}}=\frac{1}{r}\omega^\hat{\phi}\\ \theta^\hat{\theta}_{\hat{\phi}}=\frac{\cot(\theta)}{r}\omega^\hat{\theta}$$
Now turning to the second structure equation, we have;
$$ R^\hat{t}_{\hat{\phi} \space \cdot\cdot}= \theta^{\hat{t}}_{\hat{r}} \wedge \theta^{\hat{r}}_{\hat{\phi}}=-\theta^{\hat{t}}_{\hat{r}} \wedge \theta^{\hat{\phi}}_{\hat{r}}\\ =-\frac{f_r}{2f}\omega^\hat{t} \wedge \frac{1}{r} \omega^\hat{\phi} = -\frac{f_r}{2\sqrt{f}}\sin(\theta) \space dt \wedge d\phi$$
So we have;
$$ R^\hat{t}_{\hat{\phi}t \phi}=\frac{\sqrt{f}}{r\sin(\theta)}R^t_{\phi t \phi}=-\frac{f_r}{2\sqrt{f}}\sin(\theta)$$
$$\therefore R^t_{\phi t \phi}=-\frac{f_r}{2f}r\sin^2(\theta)$$
Which confirms your earlier calculation. It is worth noting that we may also write this component of our Riemann tensor in the orthonormal basis as;
$$R^\hat{t}_{\hat{\phi} \hat{t} \hat{\phi}}=-\frac{f_r}{2r{f}}$$
Which now has the spherical symmetry that you wanted but it is entirely a coincidence of our chosen basis. While the scalar curvature of a sphere is, indeed, spherically symmetric the individual components of the Riemann tensor are under no obligation to have that property. A $\textit{tensor}$ and an $\textit{invariant}$ are not the same thing.
